# Notification on Test completion

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

We are currently setting up a QA process using Azure DevOps Testplans.

I wonder if there is a possibility to get informed about changing concerning the test completeion?
Example: I develop a set of changes and define a testplan for these changes and all other products / modules / ... which might be affected by this change. I then assign the Tests to other developers.
This is the first point where I would expect the developer to be informed that he has been assignned as tester.

Now, after the tester completes his test, there should be a possibility that I get informed about the process (test completed) and - especially if there were findings - the status (Test x failed).

I tried the "Follow" option on the corresponding tests but I won't receive any info.

Next I tested the notification configuration and created a subscription for "changes on workitems owned by me" and "assigned to me" - same result: if the tester completes his test, I won't receive any info...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a possibility to get informed about changing concerning the test completeion?

I am afraid there is no such out of way to get informed about changing concerning the test completion.

If the test run with a build pipeline, we could created a subscription for `A build completes` to to get informed about test completion.

If the test run without build pipeline, we could only created a subscription for "changes on workitems owned by me" and "assigned to me", but this need the tester update the workitem state after completing his test.

If you want a directly way to get informed about changing concerning the test completion, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I just opened a feature request as described. :-) However, seemingly there is a bug on the mentioned site - you can't edit a request once it is posted ("internal error... we are sorry..."). Just found some typo in my request and wanted to correct it.

Comment: @Tyron78, There are three horizontal dots in the upper right corner of the post, click on it to have an edit option, use it to edit the post you submitted

Comment: Yes, I did this - and as soon as I press "Save" I get the error message mentioned above ("Internal Error...")